# How to compile Fortran FUNCTION/SUBROUTINE in separate files into a single MODULE

Tags: fortran, include, gfortran

Usually, when I write a collection of Fortran functions, I put them into a `MODULE` like this:

```
!mystuff.f90
MODULE mymodule
IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS

  SUBROUTINE mysubroutine1(a,b)
  !code
  END SUBROUTINE

  SUBROUTINE mysubroutine2(a,b)
  !code
  END SUBROUTINE

  !lots more functions and subroutines

END MODULE
```

and I successfully compile it like this  `gfortran -c mystuff.f90`. This creates `mystuff.o` which I can use in my main program.

However, the number and individual sizes of functions/subroutines in my `MODULE` have become so huge, that I really need to split up this up into different files.

```
!mysubrtn1.f90
SUBROUTINE mysubroutine1(a,b)
!code
END SUBROUTINE
```

and

```
! mysubrtn2.f90
SUBROUTINE mysubroutine2(a,b)
!code
END SUBROUTINE
```

and so forth...

But I'd still like to keep all these functions inside a *single* `MODULE`.  How can I tell the compiler to compile the functions in `mysubrtn1.f90`, `mysubrtn2.f90`, ... such that it produces a single module in a `.o` file?

Comment: If you have a recent compiler you should probably investigate the recently introduced `submodule` capabilities of Fortran.  Look hard enough and you'll find Qs and As hereabouts on the topic.  Not only do `submodules` allow you to break large modules into smaller pieces, they allow you to separate interface and implementation.  This is often useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply use [`include`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.4/g77/INCLUDE.html) to include another file of Fortran source code:

```
!mystuff.f90
MODULE mymodule
IMPLICIT NONE

CONTAINS

  include 'mysubrtn1.f90'
  include 'mysubrtn2.f90'

  !lots more functions and subroutines

END MODULE
```

From [here](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0580.htm):

> The INCLUDE statement directs the compiler to stop reading statements
>   from the current file and read statements in an included file or text

So you can see that the resulting module will still contain both subroutines.

---

An alternative that achieves the same thing is to use a pre-processor directive, if your compiler supports it:

```
#include "filename"
```

Comment: Very nice!  Quick followup question:  In each of my functions I have `USE xyz`.  Obviously, I can take that line out from each file and put it at the beginning of `mystuff.f90`.  But is there any harm in leaving it in every file *and* also at the beginning of `mystuff.f90`?

Comment: Do you mean what the difference is between the scope of the module or the scope of a function/subroutine?

Comment: I think I understand that difference.  Putting `USE xyz` at the top of `mystuff.f90` will make `xyz` available to all functions/subroutines in that module.  I just have a habit of *also* including it inside *every one* of those functions/subroutines.  (I think this makes no difference); I'm just wondering if I'm confusing the compiler if I have `USE xyz` at the beginning of `mystuff.f90` *and* also inside every one of the functions/subroutines.  Do correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Are there problems with using this technique with `make`, since the changes to the `include`d files won't trigger a rebuild on the parent file? Would [submodules](https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2015/07/07/doctor-fortran-in-we-all-live-in-a-yellow-submodule) help with this?

Comment: That's a good point, @arclight. To solve that problem I think you would just need to include your subroutine files as dependencies of the `mystuff.o` module.

Answer (score 2):

For readability, it is nice to separate a large module into more manageable chunks. Each of the smaller modules may be compiled individually, and used in another "master" module which is then used in the main program. The main benefit of this approach is that you can have a variety of very general modules, and pick only the procedures/data that are useful at the moment. For example:

```
module mod_1
    implicit none
    subroutine proc_1
        ! ...
    end subroutine
    ! other procedures, etc.
end module mod_1
```

And so on, for each of your separate modules. Then collect them in a single module.

```
module collection
    use mod_1, only: proc_1  ! pick & choose what to use
    use mod_2
    use mod_3
    ! ...
end module collection
```

```
program main
    use collection
    implicit none
    ! ...
end program main
```

When you compile the main program, you can link to each of the necessary object files, or even combine them into a single archive/library and just link to that.

Comment: Ok, so another strategy is to define a separate module for each my functions, and then put those modules into a bigger module.  Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: That's right. I just expanded a bit on the original answer. Athough, I think that @Alexander Vogt's answer accomplishes the same task with fewer compilation steps!